# Run command on receiving email

Tags: linux, email, debian, raspberry-pi

So I'm setting up a raspberry pi at home to automate some tasks.
I'd like it to run a terminal command when it receives an email.

Not sure exactly how to go about doing this.

Ideally I'd also like it to filter only messages from certain email addresses too.
The command would most likely be in the subject line of the email.

Running Debian it's always on via ethernet.

Thanks guys

Comment: I haven't tried much TBH, but  I've installed dovecot and postfix

Comment: Are you planning to connect your Raspberry Pi global network and setup MX record? Or, are you polling a remote POP/IMAP server from Raspberry Pi? BTW, we have http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ in public beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [pipe alias](https://serverfault.com/a/140130/7360) in your MTA and then have the script parse the email from stdin.